# Upgrade h2 dependency in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, h2

I'm working on a spring boot (2.5.2) application that uses a H2 (1.4.200) database for the local environment. The h2 dependency is explicitly declared in one of the build.gradle.kts file

```
implementation("com.h2database:h2:1.4.200")
```

As you may know, there's a [vulnerability](https://www.zdnet.com/article/jfrog-researchers-find-jndi-vulnerability-in-h2-database-consoles-similar-to-log4shell/) in the h2 console and it's recommended to upgrade h2 to the latest version (2.0.206). At first, I thought it was only a matter of changing the version number in the build.gradle.kts file but even then, when I launched the application on my environment, the h2 version was still 1.4.200

I noticed later that spring boot itself uses the 1.4.200 version of H2 by default. Is there a way to force spring boot to use the latest version of h2 ?

Comment: 1. spring doesn't "use it" but "manages the dependency version".  2. `implementation("com.h2database:h2:2.0.206")` or `ext['h2.version'] = '2.0.206'` should do the job...except when "something is interfering"